# Optimize generation of random colours

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, math

I am just starting out with Javascript and I made my first ever little project so I apologize if the code is bad and hurts your eyes.

I made a color palette generator that creates random hex color codes looping through an array.

I was wondering if there is a better way to do it, perhaps using only one loop and get three different hex codes at the same time?

```js
//declare variables to store color codes visible on dom
const hexCode01 = document.querySelector('.hex-color-code-01');
const hexCode02 = document.querySelector('.hex-color-code-02');
const hexCode03 = document.querySelector('.hex-color-code-03');

//declare variables to store color each box
const box01 = document.querySelector('.box-01');
const box02 = document.querySelector('.box-02');
const box03 = document.querySelector('.box-03');

//declare variables to store action button
const changeBtn = document.querySelector('.change-button');

//declare array to store hex digits
const hexValues = ["0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"];

changeBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
  //change button content after first click
  if (changeBtn.innerHTML === 'Generate Palette') changeBtn.innerHTML = 'Generate New Palette';
  else {
    changeBtn.innerHTML = 'Generate New Palette';
  }
  let activeHex1 = "#";
  let activeHex2 = "#";
  let activeHex3 = "#";

  //generate first color
  for (let i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    const indexBox1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * hexValues.length);
    activeHex1 += hexValues[indexBox1];
  }

  //generate second color
  for (let i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    const indexBox2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * hexValues.length);
    activeHex2 += hexValues[indexBox2];
  }

  //generate thitd color
  for (let i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    const indexBox3 = Math.floor(Math.random() * hexValues.length);
    activeHex3 += hexValues[indexBox3];

  }

  let bodyColor1 = (hexCode01.innerHTML = activeHex1);
  let bodyColor2 = (hexCode02.innerHTML = activeHex2);
  let bodyColor3 = (hexCode03.innerHTML = activeHex3);

  box01.style.backgroundColor = bodyColor1;
  box02.style.backgroundColor = bodyColor2;
  box03.style.backgroundColor = bodyColor3;
});
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 1rem;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.color-box {
  width: 33.333%;
  height: 100%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background: #ffffff;
}

button {
  background: none;
  border: 2px solid #000;
  bottom: 1rem;
  border-radius: 50px;
  padding: 1rem;
  position: fixed;
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 0.8rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #000;
  cursor: pointer;
}

button:hover {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
}

button:active {
  color: #fdfdfd;
  border-color: #fdfdfd;
}
```

```html
<div class="color-box box-01">
  <div class="hex-color-code-01">#ffffff</div>
</div>
<div class="color-box box-02">
  <div class="hex-color-code-02">#ffffff</div>
</div>
<div class="color-box box-03">
  <div class="hex-color-code-03">#ffffff</div>
</div>
<button class="change-button">Generate Palette</button>
```

Thanks

Comment: This question seems better suited for [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Please use below code where I have done it using one loop:

```
   for (let i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    const indexBox1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * hexValues.length);
    const indexBox2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * hexValues.length);
    const indexBox3 = Math.floor(Math.random() * hexValues.length);
    
    activeHex1 += hexValues[indexBox1];
    activeHex2 += hexValues[indexBox2];
    activeHex3 += hexValues[indexBox3];
  }
```

Here is jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/0yhubLn1/

Answer (score 0):

you could use one loop like so:

```js
  for (let i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    const indexBox1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * hexValues.length);
    activeHex1 += hexValues[indexBox1];
    
    const indexBox2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * hexValues.length);
    activeHex2 += hexValues[indexBox2];
    
    const indexBox3 = Math.floor(Math.random() * hexValues.length);
    activeHex3 += hexValues[indexBox3];
  }
```

Hope that is what you imagined.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const hexValues = ["0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"];
document.querySelector('.change-button').addEventListener("click", () => {
  document.querySelector('.change-button').innerHTML = 'Generate New Palette';
  let activeHex = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    activeHex[i] = '#';
    for (let j = 0; j < 6; j++) {
      activeHex[i] += hexValues[Math.floor(Math.random() * hexValues.length)];
    }
    document.querySelector('.box-' + i).style.backgroundColor = (document.querySelector('.hex-color-code-' + i).innerHTML = activeHex[i]);
  }
});
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 1rem;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.color-box {
  width: 33.333%;
  height: 100%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background: #ffffff;
}

button {
  background: none;
  border: 2px solid #000;
  bottom: 1rem;
  border-radius: 50px;
  padding: 1rem;
  position: fixed;
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 0.8rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #000;
  cursor: pointer;
}

button:hover {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
}

button:active {
  color: #fdfdfd;
  border-color: #fdfdfd;
}
```

```html
<div class="color-box box-0">
  <div class="hex-color-code-0">#ffffff</div>
</div>
<div class="color-box box-1">
  <div class="hex-color-code-1">#ffffff</div>
</div>
<div class="color-box box-2">
  <div class="hex-color-code-2">#ffffff</div>
</div>
<button class="change-button">Generate Palette</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
hexcode = () => {
        const hexValues = ["0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"];
        let hex = '#';
        for (let i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
            let index = Math.floor(Math.random() * hexValues.length);
            hex += hexValues[index];
        }
        return hex;
     }
console.log(hexcode());
```

This function will generate a random hex.

```
let activeHex1 = hexcode();
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the `hexValues` array.

`0` to `FFFFFF` in hexadecimal is `0` to `16777215` in decimal. You can select a random number between (and including) those two limits and convert to hexadecimal making sure to left pad with `0`s. We need to use `16777215 + 1 = 16777216` in the function to ensure `16777215` is a potential output:

```js
function randomColour() {
  var randInt = Math.floor(Math.random() * 16777216); // random between 0 and 16777215
  var randHex = randInt.toString(16); // convert to hexadecimal
  var randColour = "#" + randHex.padStart(6, "0"); // pad left with 0s if hex is less than 6 chars
  return randColour; // return the random hex value
}

console.log(randomColour());
```

To return 3 (or any number of) hex value colours at the same time, use an array mapping:

```js
function randomColour() {
  var randInt = Math.floor(Math.random() * 16777216);
  var randHex = randInt.toString(16);
  var randColour = "#" + randHex.padStart(6, "0");
  return randColour;
}

var numColours = 3; // your code has 3 random colours, adjust this for N colours
var colours = Array.from({length: numColours}, function(v) {return randomColour();});

console.log(colours);
```

This is a more concise way of doing what you mention in your question:

> ...perhaps using only one loop and get three different hex codes at
> the same time?

It's the same as doing this, but just in one line:

```js
function randomColour() {
  var randInt = Math.floor(Math.random() * 16777216);
  var randHex = randInt.toString(16);
  var randColour = "#" + randHex.padStart(6, "0");
  return randColour;
}

var colours = [];
var numColours = 3;
for (var i=0; i<numColours; i++) {
  colours.push(randomColour());
}

console.log(colours);
```

Applying this approach in your code:

```js
//declare variables to store color codes visible on dom
const hexCode01 = document.querySelector('.hex-color-code-01');
const hexCode02 = document.querySelector('.hex-color-code-02');
const hexCode03 = document.querySelector('.hex-color-code-03');

//declare variables to store color each box
const box01 = document.querySelector('.box-01');
const box02 = document.querySelector('.box-02');
const box03 = document.querySelector('.box-03');

//declare variables to store action button
const changeBtn = document.querySelector('.change-button');

changeBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
  //change button content after first click
  if (changeBtn.innerHTML === 'Generate Palette') changeBtn.innerHTML = 'Generate New Palette';
  else {
    changeBtn.innerHTML = 'Generate New Palette';
  }

  var colours = Array.from({length: 3}, function(v) {return randomColour();});
  
  let bodyColor1 = (hexCode01.innerHTML = colours[0]);
  let bodyColor2 = (hexCode02.innerHTML = colours[1]);
  let bodyColor3 = (hexCode03.innerHTML = colours[2]);
  
  box01.style.backgroundColor = colours[0];
  box02.style.backgroundColor = colours[1];
  box03.style.backgroundColor = colours[2];
});

function randomColour() {
  var randInt = Math.floor(Math.random() * 16777216);
  var randHex = randInt.toString(16);
  var randColour = "#" + randHex.padStart(6, "0");
  return randColour;
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 1rem;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.color-box {
  width: 33.333%;
  height: 100%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background: #ffffff;
}

button {
  background: none;
  border: 2px solid #000;
  bottom: 1rem;
  border-radius: 50px;
  padding: 1rem;
  position: fixed;
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 0.8rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #000;
  cursor: pointer;
}

button:hover {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
}

button:active {
  color: #fdfdfd;
  border-color: #fdfdfd;
}
```

```html
<div class="color-box box-01">
  <div class="hex-color-code-01">#ffffff</div>
</div>
<div class="color-box box-02">
  <div class="hex-color-code-02">#ffffff</div>
</div>
<div class="color-box box-03">
  <div class="hex-color-code-03">#ffffff</div>
</div>
<button class="change-button">Generate Palette</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

I left out most of the styling and frills to focus on JavaScript hex generation optimization:

```js
function generate() {
  var colorBoxes = document.getElementsByClassName("color-box");
  for (var i = 0; i < colorBoxes.length; i++) colorBoxes[i].innerHTML = colorBoxes[i].style.background = "#" + ("00000" + Math.floor(Math.random() * 16777216).toString(16)).slice(-6);
}
```

```css
.color-box {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 20px;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div><button onclick="generate();">Generate Palette</button></div>
<div class="color-box"></div>
<div class="color-box"></div>
<div class="color-box"></div>
```

If you want the color generation to be more random, you can use [rando.js](https://github.com/nastyox/Rando.js) instead, like this:

```js
console.log("#" + ("00000" + rando(16777215).toString(16)).slice(-6));
```

```html
<script src="http://randojs.com/2.0.0.js"></script>
```